# Control.Attributes.Add doesn't work for check box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created dynamic `checkbox` with `ID="chk"` and I want to apply inline style to it. I tried

```
chk.Attributes.Add("style","opacity:1");
```

But it doesn't work as expected. It created `span` around check box and applies style to that.
But it works

```
chk.InputAttributes["style"] = "opacity:1";
```

But former works fine for `TextBox`. Why this complexity for different controls?

**Update**

As [un-lucky answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42241046/3664659), it is just an alternative that buries my real question i.e. `Why this complexity for different controls?`. Lets forget about `style`, think of any other atrribute. Why check box is different when it comes to `Attribute.Add`?

Comment: I have added an answer below, Please let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

To add styles you have to try `Style` property instead for `Attributes` Following code will help you:

```
chkBox.Style.Add("opacity", ".3");
```

You can also try like this:

```
chkBox.Style["width"] = "70px";
chkBox.Style["height"] = "70px";
```

Comment: Thats fine, I too had a working solution as mentioned in question. My real question is `Why this complexity for different controls?` part. `Attributes.Add` works for text box not for check box. Why?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net renders two `<input>` elements for checkboxes to overcome the fact that an unchecked checkbox is not `POST`ed.

I guess the easier approach is to assign CSS classes in code, and adjust your CSS to deal with the HTML details.